# Botão não executa uma função ao ser clicado

Tags: python

Boa noite

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca TKINTER e OS no Python.
E quero que quando eu der um click no botão EXECUTAR, o programa.py execute meu arquivo.BAT.

Porém o arquivo.BAT é executado assim que o programa.py é iniciado sem o click.

Como faço para resolver esse problema?

Obrigado desde já.

Segue o código

Obs: O script TESTE que estou importando é meu modulo que esta usando a biblioteca OS para buscar o arquivo.BAT

---

```
from tkinter import *

import teste

class aplication(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.widget1 = Frame()
        self.widget1.pack()

        self.msg = Label(self.widget1, text='Problema relacionado a internet? ')
        self.msg.pack()

        self.BtnInternet = Button(self.widget1)
        self.BtnInternet["text"] = "Executar"
        self.BtnInternet.bind("<Button-1>", self.chamarbat)
        self.BtnInternet.pack()


    def chamarbat(self, event):
        return teste

root = Tk()

aplication(root)

root.mainloop()
```

---

script Teste.py

```
import os

filepath = 'C:/Users/Pc1/PycharmProjects/.BAT_SweetMix/renew.bat'

dirs = os.startfile(filepath)
```

Comment: Coloque o conteúdo de **teste.py** em uma função: `def execFile(): dirs = os.startfile(filepath)` depois chame ela: `def chamarbat(self, event): return teste.execFile()`

Comment: Deu certo. Muitissimo obrigado. Faz total sentido colocar o teste.py em uma função